# Python/Scrapy/Selenium/Phantomjs - Program blocks after some requests

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

I am making a web crawler/scraper using Python, Scrapy, Selenium and Phantomjs(for dynamically loaded content). My program looks on a Website(http://www.pcworld.com/) for some input given by the user. It then fetches links to all articles in the search result. A request is started for each of those articles. The code then fetches the title, articletext, url and date of release of the article and saves it to a Mysql DB(dbname = pcworld , username = testuser , passwd = test123) .
The thing is, after fetching some articles, the program simply stops and does nothing. There is no response in the command line.

Here´s the spider :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python
'''

@param: scrapy crawl pcworld_spider -a external_input="EXAMPLEINPUT"

'''

import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import lxml.html
import json
import MySQLdb
from Thesis.items import ThesisItem


class PcworldSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pcworld_spider"
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'Thesis.pipelines.PcworldPipeline': 50
        }
    }                   
    allowed_domains = ['pcworld.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.pcworld.com/search?query=']
    global_next_page = ''


    def __init__(self, external_input):
        self.external_input = external_input

        super(PcworldSpider, self).__init__()    #rufe ich auf um external_input an pipeline zu übergeben

        self.start_urls[0] = self.start_urls[0] + external_input
        self.global_next_page = self.start_urls[0]

        # Open database connection
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","pcworld" )
        # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

        # Drop table if it already exist using execute() method.    #whitespace entfernen wegen mysql
        self.cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s" %external_input.replace(" ", ""))

        # Create table as per requirement    #whitespace entfernen wegen mysql
        sql = """CREATE TABLE """+external_input.replace(" ", "")+""" (
                 Ueberschrift  varchar(1500),
                 Article  text,
                 Datum date,  
                 Original_URL varchar(1500))""" 

        try:
            # Execute the SQL command
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            # Commit your changes in the database
            self.db.commit()
        except:
            print("   ")
            print("IM ROLLING BACK in PARSE")
            print("   ")
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            self.db.rollback()


        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Sonstiges\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 4)    #wartet bis zu 4 sekunden



    def parse(self, response):
        print("\n1\n")
        self.driver.get(self.global_next_page)
        print("\n2\n")
        #wartet bis zu 4 sekunden(in __init__() definiert) auf den Eintritt der Condition, danach schmeist er den TimeoutException error
        try:    
            self.driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CLASS_NAME, "excerpt-text")))
            print("Found : excerpt-text")

        except TimeoutException:
            #closeself.driver.close()
            print(" excerpt-text NOT FOUND IN PCWORLD !!!")

        print("\n3\n")
        #Crawle durch Javascript erstellte Inhalte mit Selenium
        ahref = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="excerpt-text"]/h3/a')
        print("\n4\n")
        hreflist = []
        #Alle Links zu den jeweiligen Artikeln sammeln
        for elem in ahref :
            hreflist.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))

        print("\n5\n")
        for elem in hreflist :
            print(elem)
            #self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=elem , callback=self.parse_content)                        
        print("\n6\n")
        #Den Link fuer die naechste Seite holen
        try:    
            if(self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@rel='next']")):
                #print("es gibt next")
                next = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@rel='next']")
                self.global_next_page = next.get_attribute("href")

                yield scrapy.Request(url=self.global_next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)              #das ist der richtige Request!

                print(" ")
            else:
                print("next gibt es nicht!")


        except TimeoutException:
            print("TIMEOUTEXCEPTION WHILE SEARCHING FOR NEXT")
            #self.driver.close()
        print("\n7\n")


    def parse_content(self, response):       
        print("\n8\n")    
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        print("\n9\n")
        title = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h1[@itemprop='headline']")
        titletext = title.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        titletext = titletext.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')   #newlines/carriagereturns entfernen weil sonst lxml fehler schmeißt
        titletext = lxml.html.fromstring(titletext).text_content()

        date = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//meta[@name='date']")
        date_text = date.get_attribute("content")

        article = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@itemprop, 'articleBody')]//p")
        article_list = []
        print("\n10\n")
        for elem in article:
            print(" ")
            elem_text = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")
            elem_text = elem_text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')   #newlines/carriagereturns entfernen weil sonst lxml fehler schmeißt
            #print(elem_text.encode("utf-8"))
            article_list.append(elem_text)

        article_text = ' '.join(article_list)               #article Liste in einen String umwandeln
        article_text = lxml.html.fromstring(article_text).text_content()

        pcworld_data = ThesisItem()
        pcworld_data['Ueberschrift'] = titletext
        pcworld_data['Article'] = article_text
        pcworld_data['Datum'] = date_text
        pcworld_data['Original_URL'] = response.url
        print("\n11\n")            
        #returns the item -> next thing called is Pipeline with class ThesisItem()
        return pcworld_data
```

pipeline code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import MySQLdb
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twisted.internet import reactor
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request


class PcworldPipeline(object):
    global_external_input = ''

    #wird von der spider aufgerufen um das argument zu übergeben
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.global_external_input = spider.external_input.replace(" ", "") #whitespace entfernen wegen mysql

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","pcworld" )
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        data = item
        data["Ueberschrift"] = data["Ueberschrift"].replace("'", '"')   # replace ' with " because of sql 
        data["Article"] = data["Article"].replace("'", '')   # replace ' with nothing because of sql   

        #data['Article'] = data['Article'].replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(u"\u2019", "'")


        # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
        sql = """INSERT INTO {0} (Ueberschrift, Article, Datum, Original_URL)
         VALUES ('{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')
         """.format(self.global_external_input , data['Ueberschrift'].encode('utf-8'), data['Article'].encode('utf-8'), 
                    data['Datum'].encode('utf-8'), data['Original_URL']) 



        #print(sql.encode("utf-8"))
        #print(sql)
        try:
            # Execute the SQL command
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            # Commit your changes in the database
            self.db.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("  ")
            print("ROLLBACK IN PROCESS_ITEM")
            print(e)
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            self.db.rollback()


        return item
```

my item :

```
import scrapy


class ThesisItem(scrapy.Item):
    Ueberschrift = scrapy.Field()
    Article = scrapy.Field()
    Datum = scrapy.Field()
    Original_URL = scrapy.Field()
```

things changed in the settings :

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 200
CONCURRENT_ITEMS = 400
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 4
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

What i observed :

The program always stops after calling self.driver.get(response.url) in parse_content
The database is not related to the code blocking ( i tried removing everything and funneling the items into a json file )
I have similar code for other websites, and on some of them it works perfectly, but here it blocks.

Any suggestions on why the code stops after some (4 - 10) article requests?

output :  (last few lines before it blocks)

```
6

2017-07-25 09:52:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:60768/wd/hub/session/31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b/elements {"using": "xpath",
 "sessionId": "31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b", "value": "//a[@rel='next']"}
2017-07-25 09:52:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-07-25 09:52:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:60768/wd/hub/session/31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b/element {"using": "xpath",
"sessionId": "31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b", "value": "//a[@rel='next']"}
2017-07-25 09:52:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-07-25 09:52:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:60768/wd/hub/session/31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b/element/:wdc:1500969177413/a
ttribute/href {"sessionId": "31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b", "name": "href", "id": ":wdc:1500969177413"}
2017-07-25 09:52:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request


7

2017-07-25 09:53:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.pcworld.com/article/2142565/report-nsa-secretly-exploited-devastating-heartbleed-bug-for-years.html> (
referer: http://www.pcworld.com/search?query=heartbleed&start=10)

8

2017-07-25 09:53:01 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:60768/wd/hub/session/31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b/url {"url": "http://www.pcw
orld.com/article/2142565/report-nsa-secretly-exploited-devastating-heartbleed-bug-for-years.html", "sessionId": "31152680-710e-11e7-bb53-730b5237f77b"}
```

another test i did : output : https://pastebin.com/XAky7YJP     ( here it stopped after the first request)

I am using python 2.7 and scrapy 1.4.0

Comment: Can you paste the complete cmd line logs?

Comment: @kiran.koduru hey !, i added the last few lines of output before the program "blocks". I let the program run for 2 hours, and to my surprise when i came back it was actually finished . Still the problem persists that after a certain amount of requests the program seems to freeze for atleast 30min to 1 hour. I am not sure if it always unfreezes and finishes, since i normally don´t let the program run for that long. Would you happen to know what´s causing that freeze?

Comment: Can you paste the full logs to https://pastebin.com/? I am guessing, scrapy logs can give you more info on what might be the issue if you looked closely at the timestamps.

Comment: @kiran.koduru hey, i added a link to 1 test , and here´s another ( only the last ~100 lines) : https://pastebin.com/mxF5e3a6 
(after waiting for 1 hour i shut the program down with ctrl + c )

Comment: Since you aren't using the scrapy downloader, you won't see what's going on in the background for selenium. If you can configure your web driver instance to give you more log info, that way you can get an idea of what might go wrong. But if all else fails, I would suggest try using [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) which could give you more info on your request data. Hope that helps.